# C#: Configuring a project for x64 platform in AnyCPU codebase

Tags: c#, msbuild, target-platform, anycpu

In my codebase there's a utility project of type `lib`: `MyCode.Utility` with `TargetPlatform` set to `AnyCPU` in its `*.csproj` file.

The project is then referenced by an executable, which also targets `AnyCPU`.

Now I need to introduce a new `exe` project to my codebase and due to its dependencies it has to target `x64` only instead of `AnyCPU`. I would also like the new project to reference `MyCode.Utility`.

How shall I configure my projects? In particular I'd like to ensure that my shared library is compiled to the right target, depending on which executable triggers the compilation.

Comment: Since `MyCode.Utility` still has no dependency to X64, but only the new executable (AFAICT), you can simply reference the AnyCPU `MyCode.Utility` form the X64 executable project. You can always reference AnyCPU from all other platforms. Just not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the shared library doesn't have any dependencies. Moreover, I noticed there's a property `Platforms` that I can set in my `*.csproj`. Do I need to use it as well or maybe setting `TargetPlatform` to `AnyCPU` or `x64` is enough?